How to filter out data from a enterprise geodatabase using traditional versioning
I am using ArcGIS Pro 3.3, PostgreSQL 14 and ArcGIS Server 11.3.0.
I have a enterprise geodatabase that is using traditional versioning. It consists of around 20 feature classes, where every feature class have a field called project.
I know I can assign different persons to a version, so they are not working on default, but is it possible to give person A a "view" of the geodatabase, so they can only see data where project = X, and another user only project = Y?

You could try to play with versioned views, but this is not the purpose of versioning, and working across purpose is likely to get ugly, quickly.
